# Why Is the Possuk Read Backwards?

Tags: minhag, prayer-book, chabad, sleep, vayechi

The verse in [Bereishis 49:19](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0149.htm#19) states:

> גָּ֖ד גְּד֣וּד יְגוּדֶ֑נּוּ וְה֖וּא יָגֻ֥ד עָקֵֽב

Is is the Chabad Minhag to [read](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16091&st=&pgnum=306) this verse, followed by the reverse of it, as part of Krias Shema She'al HaMita.

What is the source for reading it backwards and what is the intended meaning?

Comment: The passuk itself is talking about returning(going backwards from where they came) see Rashi there.

Comment: To make sure you haven't fallen asleep yet :)

Comment: I haven't seen it in other Nuschao's, if anyone has more info please share.

Comment: It's Kabalistic, and its origin is (AFAICT) the Arizal. The [Nagid U'Mitzva](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=9538#p=p105) (written by a student of the Ari, R' [Yaakov Tzemach](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/יעקב_צמח_(מקובל))) says its purpose (as well as that of the surrounding verses) is "להנצל מקרי". Rabbi Yitzchak Ginsburg has some [kabalistic](http://haparasha.blogspot.com/2008/07/blog-post_17.html) [explanations](http://www.malchuty.org/2011-01-20-01-37-36/2011-01-20-02-06-32/213--q-.html), but nothing explaining why it's in Krias Shema.

Comment: Continued: [Siddur Rabbeinu HaZakein](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=30450#p=p427) references some Siddurei HaArizal, but I did not find online copies of them. The [Mishnas Chassidim](http://books.google.com/books?id=N6I8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PT125&lpg=PT125&dq="גד+גדוד"+ישר+והפוך) also brings it, with the same reason as the Nagid Umitzva (and likely the same source).

Comment: @HodofHod: It is said only by Kriyas Shema Al hamita where one requires the protection of Keri.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Sefer Lidrosh Elokim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32968&st=&pgnum=31) mentions in the name of the [Shevet Musar 40](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31545&st=&pgnum=178) in the name of [Sefer Kanfei Yonah 3:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7367&st=&pgnum=139&hilite=) that saying גָּ֖ד גְּד֣וּד יְגוּדֶ֑נּוּ וְה֖וּא יָגֻ֥ד עָקֵֽב three times the regular way and three times backwards is a protection for Keri.

Comment: Do any of them explain why doing this procedure with this verse protects against Keri?

Comment: @DoubleAA: They do, however it is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: So you're just assuming they do...

Comment: @DoubleAA: I am not assuming. They give a reason which I do not understand.